# In ”The Cabin in the Woods”, what was the significance of the locket?

Tags: movie, horror, the-cabin-in-the-woods

In the basement of the titular Cabin in the Woods, there are a series of objects which represent different horrors waiting to be unleashed;

There's the puzzle box (representing the Cenobytes), the conch shell (representing the Merman), the diary which was the Zombie Redneck family, the Music Box (representing the Sugar-Plum Fairy) and a locket.

What was the locket's counterpart?

Comment: You may wish to reconsider your acceptance. My research suggests that the locket matched up with the werewolf, not the female ghost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The locket (actually an amulet) would have summoned The Werewolf

The official [novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7980210-the-cabin-in-the-woods) indicates that the item around the dress-maker's doll is the amulet.

> *Jules had removed the golden amulet from around the dummy’s neck and
>   was holding it to her own neck, staring into a dusty mirror to see how
>   it looked, and Dana thought that in the mirror her friend looked as
>   old as everything else down here. Jules searched for the clasp as if
>   to try it on for real.*

The film's Director (and writer) Drew Goddard indicated in [this webchat](http://io9.com/5944666/cabin-in-the-woods-director-drew-goddard-is-live-on-io9-and-taking-your-questions) that wearing the amulet would have summoned **the Werewolf**.

> **@MisterGoddard**
>
> *Clown was a fortune teller machine, Unicorn was a
>   Unicorn Tapestry (you can see it in the background), **Werewolf was an
>   amulet**, and Sasquatch was a large jar of Eau De Sasquatch.
>   (That last one might not be true.)*

Answer (score 8):

The locket came off of a wedding dress ensemble.

It seems to have matched up with the female ghost.

Comment: The wedding dress appears to be a separate item. The Bride would have been summoned only if the Virgin (or the Whore) had decided to wear the wedding dress.

Answer (score 6):

May have been a reference to the locket Ash gives his girlfriend in Evil Dead.  The music box also a mix of Evil Dead, Suspiria, and most recently Black Swan.

Comment: Like when all the elevator doors are opened for the first time in the bunker, and a bunch of tree-branches come out of one of them.